# Parse a .dat file in c++

Tags: c++, string, file, ifstream, stringstream

I have a .dat file but each line is different. 
I mean that there are a lines with `double` and a lines with string.

I can read the file and even to parse it but something get wrong with the strings.
if I have a line with only "A" as a string it gives me the string with space. I don't 
know what is wrong but here is

**My code:**

```
ifstream file;
file.open(name,ios::in|ios::binary);
vector<string> strings;
string line;

if (file.is_open())
{
    while(file.good())
    {
        vector<double> vdoubles;

        getline(file,line,'\n');
        stringstream ss(line);

        double num= 0.0;
        string str = ss.str();

        if (! (ss >> num)) // if this is a string and not double
        {
            strings.push_back(str);
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                vdoubles.push_back(num);
            }while ( ss >> num);


        }
    }
}
```

**an example of the .dat file:**

```
A
0.02 0.4 0.6
BC
0.45 0.5 0.8
```

when I'm debugging I see the strings vector as it should be, but when I'm printing the vector it prints with spaces between the elements of the vector even though I print it as

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
    cout << strings[i];
cout << endl;
```

so why it also give me the spaces?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames are you sure? now when i try to print the vector it prints about the previous elements.. i don't know what is wrong! its driving me crazy! :)

Comment: Are there possibly spaces in the .dat file?

Comment: I posted a sample of the .dat file. each line is separated by enter key. and between the double values there are spaces.

Comment: Not entirely sure...  One thought is that it could be reading the spaces between the doubles as strings, since you are looking for the new lines as your separator.

Comment: ok, but if it does as you say, so when i read the first line which contains "A" and store it in the vector, it doesn't need to contain space after the letter. no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so the answer is that you can't use the same stringstream to parse different types.
so this is the solution

```
    if (! (ss >> num)) // if this is a string and not double
    {
        stringstream l;
        l << line;
        l >> str;   
        strings.push_back(str);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            vdoubles.push_back(num);
        }while ( ss >> num);


    }
```